# Как привязать к одной кнопке сразу несколько форм?

Tags: html

Всем привет, есть 4 формы на странице и одна кнопка, как привязать формы к этой кнопке?

Нашел атрибут `form`, прописал всем формам одинаковый `id`, но при клике на кнопку проверяется только самая верхняя форма.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `id` - должен быть уникальным, ВСЕГДА

Comment: @meine а как их передать в один атрибут form?

Comment: не понял, вы хотите по нажатию на 1 кнопку отправить данные с 4 форм сразу?

Comment: @meine да, в макете только одна кнопка

Comment: а почему не используете одну форму для этого, а 4 разных?

Comment: @meine я даже как то не задумывался об этом) дизайн сделан так и кажется, что это разные формы

Comment: не стоит усложнять себе жизнь) делайте через 1 форму и будет Вам счастье

Comment: @meine спасибо!:)

Comment: желаю успехов и больших побед!